The function replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim() and trim() is not good working for input value
I tried to use replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim() as well as just .trim() but it's not working.
I want to remove any spaces typed in input1 from input2 and input3. Please help.


var input1 = document.getElementById('myInput1');
var input2 = document.getElementById('myInput2');
var input3 = document.getElementById('myInput3');

  input1.addEventListener('change', function() {
    input2.value = input1.value + "@gmail.com".replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();
    input3.value = input1.value + "@gmail.com".trim();
  });
<input type="text" id="myInput1" />
<input type="text" id="myInput2" />
<input type="text" id="myInput3" />




You're removing spaces from @gmail.com, not the user's input. It should be input1.value.replace(...).


var input1 = document.getElementById('myInput1');
var input2 = document.getElementById('myInput2');
var input3 = document.getElementById('myInput3');

  input1.addEventListener('change', function() {
    input2.value = input1.value.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim() + "@gmail.com";
    input3.value = input1.value.trim() + "@gmail.com";
  });
<input type="text" id="myInput1" />
<input type="text" id="myInput2" />
<input type="text" id="myInput3" />




Thank you but it's not working either. When I type "hey hey", it currently shows "hey hey@gmail.com" instead of "heyhey@gmail.com" in input2 and input3.

You're replacing multiple spaces with a single space. If you want to remove the spaces entirely, replace them with an empty string.

Okay. Looks like it's because of the spacing in replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim(). When I remove the space between the single quotes, it works. Thank You.

That's exactly what I said. I assumed that was intentional, that you just wanted to remove extra spaces.

Otherwise there's no need to call .trim(), since replacing all spaces will remove surrounding spaces as well.
